# Node.js Redis subscribe callback not executing

Tags: node.js, redis, callback, publish-subscribe

I'm building an application where I use a Redis connection between 2 services(API-gateway and notifications). For this connection, I use the pub/sub method of Redis. The library I use is called NRP.

The problem is that I can pass data from the API-gateway to the Notifications, but the data I need back is not being received by the API-gateway. Imagine I want to log in, then the API-gateway publishes the username and password to the notifications. In the notifications, all the logic for the login is being done and when it's all good, I sent a message back to the API-gateway.

Code from the API-gateway(where subchannel and pubchannel are given as parameters to the function):

```
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                try {
                        this.sub.Subscribe(subchannel, (data, channel) => {

                            let body = data.body;      
                            let message = body.message;     
                            if(data.rmid == data.mid){
                                sub.unSubscribe((nrp)=>{
                                    nrp.quit();
                                    resolve(message);
                                });
                            }

                        }); 
                        const sent = this.sub.publish(pubchannel, {
                        body: {
                                param: params,
                                message: '',
                              }
                        });



                } catch (e) {
                    reject(e);
                }
            });
}
```

Code from the sub.Subscribe part above, also the part where subscribing to the publish happens:

```
Subscribe(pattern, callback)
{
    console.log('Im gonna subscribe');
    console.log(pattern);
    nrp.on(pattern, (data, channel) => {
        console.log('subd on ' + pattern);
       return callback(data, channel);
    });


}
```

So the problem is, the moment i publish on the notificationservice to tell the Api-gateway the login is succesvol, it doesnt trigger the callback on the subscribe in the API-gateway. 
The code on the notificationservice is correct, because if i subscribe on the redis-client application, it works. and if publish on the redis-client application it shows i have 1 listener, so the Api-Gateway is listening. Somehow the callback is not being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soo i figured it out. Apperently i need to json-encode the message before i sent it, otherwise the nrp library wont pick it up.